# swprintf and vswprintf not declared?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, botan

I am trying to compile Botan on Windows with MinGW, and am receiving the following error during compilation:

```
c:\qt\2010.04\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/cwchar:159: error:
'::swprintf' has not been declared
c:\qt\2010.04\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/cwchar:166: error:
'::vswprintf' has not been declared
```

Why are swprintf and vswprintf not declared, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did any of you file a bug report at Qt?

Comment: Just a note, `vswprintf` should actually be called as [`wvsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647551(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows.

You'd expect it to be `vwsprintf()` or `vwcsprintf()` or something following the other conventions, but `wvsprintf()` it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting in

```
#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
```

before including stdio.h

Comment: Or don't compile with the -ansi switch? Looks like buggy headers.

Comment: Compiling with `-std=c++0x` seems to cause this even without an explicit `-ansi` (in ye olde MinGW GCC 4.4.0). A newer GCC should fix it (and make `-std=c++0x` redundant) but I haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem compiling Grantlee using MinGW (Qt 2010.05).

How I got it to compile:

- find file cwchar (C:\Qt\2010.05\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\cwchar)
- comment the following lines out (around line 160)

  using ::swprintf;

  using ::vswprintf;

Answer (score 2):

When running make ensure that -ansi flag is not set. If this flag is being used then remove it and the problem will be solved.