# `#include <iostream>` with `-std=c++0x` is broken

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, g++, c++11

If I specify `-std=c++0x` to g++, then I can't `#include <iostream>`. I get the following error messages (g++ 4.4.0 under mingw):

```
In file included from c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/iosfwd:42,
                 from c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from f.cpp:1:
c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/cwchar:159: error: '::swprintf' has not been declared
c:\qt\2010.05\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/include/c++/cwchar:166: error: '::vswprintf' has not been declared
```

Any ideas why? Has this been fixed in the latest g++? (And if so, does anybody know how to incorporate the latest g++ into Qt?)

Comment: what does the compiler tells if you remove '-std=c++0x'?

Comment: This looks like a bug in MinGW's C++ library/headers, not in G++.

Comment: @Simone: Without -std=c++0x, I have no problems.

Comment: See if it applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445312/swprintf-and-vswprintf-not-declared

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a [bug](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/trying-to-compile-on-MinGW-td2497846.html). There is a [thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/ANN-GCC-4-4-0-Released-td2655349.html) with a simple patch (in the very end).

Comment: Thank you! That worked. (You might want to edit 'path' to 'patch' in your Answer.)

Answer (score 3):

```
if win32{
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x
}
else {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
}
```