# C++0x with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, mingw, qt-creator

I'm trying to use new C++0x features in [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) under Windows (Qt Creator 2.0.1).

I read the thread *[Configuring the GCC compiler switches in Qt, Qt Creator, and QMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987062/configuring-gcc-compiler-switches-in-qt-qtcreator-qmake)* and added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` to .pro file.

After it Qt Creator gives me very strange errors on this simple code:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
}
```

Compiler  errors:

> '::swprintf' has not been declared
>
> '::vswprintf' has not been declared

I try to compile my code from the command line with command `g++ test.cpp --std=c++0x` and get same error.

So what's wrong with Qt [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) compiler? Is it possible to use C++0x features in Qt Creator?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713713/include-iostream-with-std-c0x-is-broken. All you have to do is comment out `using ::swprintf;` and `using ::vswprintf;` in the library header file -- see the patch mentioned in ssmir's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it could be that the library headers just don't represent their dependencies properly.  Try adding an `#include <cstdio>` and perhaps (unfortunately) a `using namespace std;` to your file at the top.

Failing that, several people seem to have had issues with MinGW and swprintf.  [This mailing list post](http://lists-archives.org/mingw-users/17595-compilation-problem-with-swprintf.html) suggests adding this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define swprintf _snwprintf
#endif
```

See if that resolves the issue.  (You want it at the very top of the file, too.)

If prepending random defines to your source seems like a bad idea to you, I suggest using `-D` build flags to conditionally inject the above define when you're building on MinGW.

See also [this short discussion](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/6612/) on the differences between swprintf on MinGW vs. other compilers.

Finally, failing all else, [this link](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2373234&group_id=2435&atid=102435) seems to attribute the problem to an issue with flags that enable `__STRICT_ANSI__` in MinGW, and suggests commenting out a couple of lines in one of the MinGW headers to fix the issue.  I would suggest adding a simpler `#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__` around them instead if you decide to go with this hack.

Comment: I add `__STRICT_ANSI__` for '::swprintf' and `::vswprintf` and it's compiled. Thanks ;)