# Using std::tr1::normal_distribution in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, random, c++11, mingw

I would like to generate numbers with normal_distribution in c++11. Using Qt 4.8 MinGW. I have added the next line

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

to my .pro file
and then get next errors:
'swprintf::' has not been declared
'vswprintf::' has not been declared

Comment: "some_symbol has not been declared" probably means you're missing a header file, if it's happening during compilation. If it's happening during linking then you're probably missing a library. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: If you use `-std=c++0x`, then you should use `std::normal_distribution`. TR1 is a library for C++98!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3445312/894321

Comment: Please copy the errors using the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TR1 really should be avoid when using C++11 as it was designed to meet the limitations of the previous standard. (also everything that was considered useful went on and became integrated into the standard.)

Luckily there is a comprehensive random number generation library in C++11 with normal distribution.

See here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

```
#include <random>
:::
std::random_device rd;
std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0,99);
std::mt19937 engine(rd());
double a=dist(engine);
```

The exact error your getting look as though the particular implementation of TR1 isn't very good anyway. (missing include or missing namespace prefix).